# Cannot create new activity in Android Studio (Mac)

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio for Mac, the option for creating new activities has disappeared from the File>New menu. Is there an alternate method to create an activity in an existing project?

Comment: Have you tried right clicking on the Java package in the Project pane (Android View)? There is a new menu there that should list Activity, among other things.

Comment: File > New > Java class... Write it yourself? ;)

Comment: Go to project structure then click **File > New > Java class**